# fragment data update from another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, fragment, android-listfragment

In my messaging app I have multiple contacts with messages . I have a main activity and two fragments, `outerFragment` and `innerFragment`.Latest message of each contact I am showing in `outerfragment` list . On click of each row of `outerfragmrnt` I am opening  `innerfragment` which contain all message of individual contact.Now when I am deleting latest message from `innerfragment` than it is deleting but it is not updating in `outerfragment`.How can I update latest message in `outerfragment` when I am deleting latest message from `innerfragment`. How to achieve this in android ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use listeners for this purpose. this can be achieved as follow

create an interface as shown below:

```
public interface myListener {
    public void updateView(boolean success, Object message);
}
```

make your `OuterFragment` implement this listener and override unimplemented methods:

```
public class OuterFragment extends Fragment implements myListener {

    onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        InnerFragment innerfrag = new InnerFragment();
        innerFrag.setmyListener(this);
    }

    updateView(boolean success, Object message) {
        // your code here
    }

}
```

create the `setmyListener()` method in InnerFragment

```
InnerFragment extends Fragment {

    myListener listener;

    public void setmyListener (myListener listener){
        this.listener = listener
    }

}
```

make a callback from `InnerFragment` to outer by calling this method when you want to update the `OuterFragment`

```
listener.updateView(success,message);
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me come up with a solution where I had a fragment (Parent) that spawned a fragment on top of it (Child A), which then moved to another (Child B) and another (Child C) and then the last (Child C) had to notify the Parent that something had changed.  One thing I will say is that your code above contains a couple of minors errors, missing `@Override public View` before `onCreateView` and `public void` before `updateView`.